# Unions of disjoint open sets.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space (hence separable) and $\mu$ a Borel
probability measure.

Given an open set $A$ and $r,\epsilon>0$ $\ $does there exist a finite set of
disjoint open balls $\left\{  B_{i}\right\}  $ contained in $A$ and of radius smaller than $r$ , so that $\mu(\cup B_{i})\geq\mu(A)-\epsilon.$

Comment: It's not easy to fill up all the volume of a box by regular and arbitrary small spheres..

Comment: @Berci, true, but if the spheres are allowed to be of different and arbitrarily small sizes then you should be able to get within $\epsilon$ with a finite number of them.

Comment: Yes, but.. how?

Comment: Robert: It is an interesting problem.  Do you have any thoughts to share on it? Where did it come from?

Comment: Buckets filled with sand certainly convince me that the answer is yes. At least in Euclidean space.

Comment: In euclidean spaces you can change the metric so the "balls" are squares, and you can easily do it. In cantor spaces, the balls of any radius form a partition of the space. My main motivation is to see if some results (that use measures) of cantor spaces also hold for compact metric spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Recall

> **Lemma (Finite Vitali covering lemma)** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $\{B(a_j,r_j),j\in [K]\}$ a finite collection of open balls. We can find a subset $J$ of $[K]$ such that the balls $B(a_j,r_j),j\in J$ are disjoint and 
>   $$\bigcup_{i\in [K]}B(a_i,r_i)\subset \bigcup_{j\in J}B(a_j,3r_j).$$

A proof is given page 41 in the book *Ergodic Theory: with a view towards Number Theory*, Einsiedler M., Ward T.

For each $a\in A$, fix $r_a<r/3$ such that $B(a,3r_a)\subset A$. As $X$ is separable, we can, by Lindelöf property, extract from the cover $\{B(a,r_a),a\in A\}$ of $A$ a countable subcover $\{B(a_j,r_j),j\in \Bbb N\}$. Now take $N$ such that $\mu(A)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=0}^NB(a_j,r_j)\right)<\varepsilon$. Then we conclude by finite Vitali covering lemma.

Comment: I love the title of the book you mention: _Ergodic theory: with a view towards ergodic theory_.

Comment: @Davide Thanks.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo actually there is something that confuses me. The Vitali covering lemma says that the balls with radius r are disjoint not the ones with radius 3r. How do we know the small balls take up almost all the measure?

Comment: @Robert You are perfectly right, my argument is wrong. Please unaccept my answer, then I will be able to delete it.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Ok. But I think you were on the right track. It seems that you can do a Vitali cover with small radius, but you have to add the extra hypothesis that the measure is doubling.

Comment: @Robert I should think more deeply on it. Anyway, I don't delete the answer because you won't be able to see it, and maybe it can give you the idea.